Using Crossvalidation to evaluate different Mutual Information Threshholds for Feature Selection
I'm currently trying to determine a mutual information threshold value for feature selection in a classification task. My idea was to set different thresholds based on location parameters e.g. median, top75%, etc., and then evaluate these thresholds via CV over the training set. Since I'm planning on deploying several different models(Naive Bayes, CART, TAN) would it then be necessary to compare the difference for each threshold for every model individually or is it sufficient to compare eg. the mean acc of threshold 1 to the mean acc of threshold 2?
Is this generally an acceptable approach or would you recommend a more scientific way?
I also tried the boruta method but the algorithm only excluded 1 out of 29 features despite many of them having a low MI Score (0,001). The models using the remaining 28 features then also performed worse in CV in comparison to the models using only top50%/75%.
Generally, I'm trying to prevent the feature selection process from being criticized as non-scientific. However many papers I read stated that there is no best way to do this.
What method would you recommend? What should be improved looking at my approach?
